# Case statement - hide/unhide based on conditional value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to hide a column if the case value is no.

I saved this in the sheet, not a module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ActiveSheet.Activate

    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C9"), Range(Target.Address)) Is     Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Value
           Case Is = "Yes":
              Rows("10:10").EntireRow.Hidden = False
           Case Is = "No":
              Rows("10:10").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End Select

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Step through the code using F8 and let us know if the "No" case is reached. Best bet is a case-sensitive fail (eg "no" instead of "No"), but there could be a number of other reasons.

Comment: How are you putting the value into C9? If by formula, you have to use the Worksheet Calculate event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's related to a **case-sensitive** fail check. 
Try this code and tell us if this solve the issue:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ActiveSheet.Activate

    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C9"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case LCase(Target.Value)
            Case Is = "yes":
                Rows("10:10").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case Is = "no":
                Rows("10:10").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End Select
    End If

End Sub
```

---

Comment: Nice! Thanks!!  it works now but if i change the value back to yes.. it doesnt unhide.

Comment: @hothatsc You're Welcome. I did some tests, and it works only if you write `yes` or `no` in the cell `C9`. Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes thank you!! it did!! Sorry to ask but is there a way to put the code as public module and call it in sheet? I'm asking because, I have a couple of rows and sheets that I would like to repeat the task. Will it make more sense to type the code once in the module, then call it whenever?

Comment: @hothatsc I'm happy that worked for you. I can help you with this, but if we want to follow the rules, I think you should open a new question and then I can answer the new one. If this was helpful, can you accept my answer? Thank you! :)

Comment: Thanks!! sure will do. apologies, completely new here :)

Comment: No problem, we're here to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

## Worksheet Calculate Event

- [Workbook
  Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a4envof2kkmuh2e/excel-vba-case-statement-hide-unhide-does-not-work-based-on-conditional-vlaue_55311335.xlsm?dl=0)
  (Dropbox)
- If `Yes` and `No` are being changed by a formula, the `Worksheet Change` event will not be triggered when the value changes.
- Copy the first code into a **standard module**, e.g. `Module1` (VBE >> Insert >> Module).
- Copy the second code into a **sheet module**, e.g. `Sheet1`.
- Copy the third code into **ThisWorkbook module**.

**Module1**

```vb
Option Explicit

Public strYesNo As String

Sub YesNo(CellRange As Range, HideRow As Long)

    Const str1 As String = "Yes"
    Const str2 As String = "No"

    With CellRange
        If .Value <> strYesNo Then
            Select Case strYesNo
                Case str1
                    .Worksheet.Rows(HideRow).Hidden = False
                Case str2
                    .Worksheet.Rows(HideRow).Hidden = True
            End Select
            strYesNo = .Value
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Sub YesNo1()

    Const cSheet As Variant = "Sheet1"
    Const cRange As String = "C9"
    Const cCol As Long = 10

    YesNo ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet).Range(cRange), cCol

End Sub
```

**Sheet1**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    YesNo1
End Sub
```

**ThisWorkbook**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    YesNo1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks all! if yes/ no is a list, does it affect anything? still doesnt seem to work.. :(

Comment: @hothatsc: I've changed the code and added a download link for the workbook.