# Repetative task for each sheet, unhide and hide base on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have this current code working, however I would like to repeat the same task for quite a few rows in a sheet and other sheets in the workbook.

The task I would like to repeat is to unhide and hide rows based on yes/ no drop down. I understand that it's possible to create a code in module and call it in each sheet. Would appreaciate help.

Thank you!!

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("C6")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target = "Yes" Then
        Rows("7:7").Hidden = False
    ElseIf Target = "No" Then
        Rows("7:7").Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The [Workbook.SheetChange Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange) will handle a change in any worksheet. What other rows besides 7 are relevant?

Comment: if 9 is yes, hide 10.. if 12 is yes, hide 13... etc. till 42.

Comment: If 9 is yes, hide 10, If 9 is no ..?

Comment: Is it possible to use a single cell for the `yes`/`no` checks or they must be one per row to hide/unhide?

Comment: unforturnately, one per row. its like a checklist for work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this, using the [Workbook.SheetChange event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange). Add this code to the `ThisWorkbook` code module. It assumes that no other cells besides your drop-downs say "Yes" or "No." It can be easily modified if that is not the case. It can also be modified to only handle certain worksheets and exclude others, if needed.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "Yes"
            Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "No"
            Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

As noted in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55312000/9245853) to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55311335/excel-vba-case-statement-hide-unhide-does-not-work-based-on-conditional-vlaue), you can use `LCase` to make this case-insensitive:

```
Select Case LCase(Target.Value)
    Case "yes"
        ....
    Case "no"
        ....
End Select
```

**EDIT**:

Modified to exclude certain sheets based on their name:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Select Case Sh.Name
        Case "Sheet2", "Sheet4" ' change to the names of the sheets to exclude
            Exit Sub
    End Select

    If VarType(Target.Value) = vbString Then
        Select Case LCase(Target.Value)
            Case "yes"
                Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case "no"
                Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This works! how do I exclude some sheet or cell? Thanks!!

Comment: See the edit for how to exclude sheets. How do you determine which cells to exclude? Based on what column and/or row they are in, for example?